# Standard way to display Bing API Truck Route JSON response on a Bing Map?

Tags: bing-maps

I'm successfully calling Bing's Truck Route API (below) to get a JSON response for a route.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/calculate-a-truck-route

What's the standard way to get that to show up on a Bing Map? From their documentation here, I can't quite tell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-a-static-map

Comment: Do you want to display it on an interactive map with the route overlaid or a do you just want a static image of a map with the line drawn on it?

Comment: @rbrundritt Interactive map, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To display a truck route result on an interactive map in Bing Maps, the easiest option is to leverage the directions module which supports truck routing. The directions module is an integrated part of the interactive map SDK. Here are some examples:

https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/directionscreatetruckroute

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/directions-module-examples/calculate-driving-directions

If you want to instead directly access the REST routing API and display the results from that on a map, you will need to loop through and extract the route points from the route response, and create a line.